# NPM Install Error (Laravel)

Tags: node.js, laravel, gulp

I'm trying to run the npm install command to install Laravel Elixir and other Gulp related packages. But when running the command, I get this error:

```
$ npm install --no-bin-links npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.6 npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0 npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.6 npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.6

    expect@1.13.4 postinstall c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-phpspec\node_modules\expect node ./npm-scripts/postinstall.js

    utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate node-gyp rebuild

| c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) else (node rebuild ) Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch. validation.cc win_delay_load_hook.c Creating library c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_mod ules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\Release\validation.lib and object c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\soc \ ket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\Release\validation.exp Generating code Finished generating code validation.vcxproj -> c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_m odules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\build\Release\validation. node npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm

    bufferutil@1.2.1 install c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil node-gyp rebuild

/ c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node- "c:\Program File) else (node rebuild ) \bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch. bufferutil.cc win_delay_load_hook.c Creating library c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_mod ules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\Release\bufferutil.lib and object c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket. / io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\Release\bufferutil.exp Generating code Finished generating code bufferutil.vcxproj -> c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_m odules\socket.io\node_modules\engine.io\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\Release\bufferutil.node

    utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate node-gyp rebuild

c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modnot defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) else (node rebuild ) Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(403,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "Release\obj\validation\validation.tlog". Het opgegeven pad, de bestandsnaam of beide zijn te lang. De volledig gekwalificeerde bestandsnaam moet minder dan 260 tekens bevatten en de mapnaam minder dan 2 48 tekens. [c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socke t.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate\bui ld\validation.vcxproj] gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe failed with exit code: 1 gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23) gyp ERR! stack at emitTwo (events.js:87:13) gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7) gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586 gyp ERR! command "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" gyp ERR! cwd c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\utf-8-validate gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.4 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3 gyp ERR! not ok

    bufferutil@1.2.1 install c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil node-gyp rebuild

c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild ) else (node rebuild ) Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(403,5): error MSB3191: Unable to create directory "Release\obj\bufferutil\bufferutil.tlog". Het opgegeven pad, de bestandsnaam of beide zijn te lang. De volledig gekwalificeerde bestandsnaam moet minder dan 260 tekens bevatten en de mapnaam minder dan 2 48 tekens. [c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socke t.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil\build\b -ufferutil.vcxproj] gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe failed with exit code: 1 gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23) gyp ERR! stack at emitTwo (events.js:87:13) gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7) gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12) gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10586 gyp ERR! command "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" cwd c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\socket.io\node_modules\socket.io-client\node_modules\engine.io-client\node_modules\ws\node_modules\bufferutil gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.4 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3 gyp ERR! not ok npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing utf-8-validate@1.2.1

    spawn-sync@1.0.15 postinstall c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\node_modules\cross-spawn\node_modules\spawn-sync node postinstall

npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing bufferutil@1.2.1 \

    node-sass@3.4.2 install c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass node scripts/install.js

Binary downloaded and installed at c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node

    node-sass@3.4.2 postinstall c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass node scripts/build.js

c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\node_modules\laravel-elixir\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-x64-46\binding.node exists. testing binary. Binary is fine; exiting. npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586 npm ERR! argv "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "--no-bin-links" npm ERR! node v4.2.4 npm ERR! npm v2.14.12 npm ERR! path C:\Users\Peer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\1.0.33\package\package.json.3e8215c2c4109ff6837b7026505d63a1 npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Peer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\1.0.33\package\package.json.3e8215c2c4109ff6837b7026505d63a1' -> 'C:\Users\Peer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\1.0.33\package\package.json' npm ERR! at Error (native) npm ERR! { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Peer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\1.0.33\package\package.json.3e8215c2c4109ff6837b7026505d63a1' -> 'C:\Users\Peer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\1.0.33\package\package.json'] npm ERR! errno: -4048, npm ERR! code: 'EPERM', npm ERR! syscall: 'rename', npm ERR! path: 'C:\Users\Peer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\1.0.33\package\package.json.3e8215c2c4109ff6837b7026505d63a1', npm ERR! dest: 'C:\Users\Peer\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\readable-stream\1.0.33\package\package.json', npm ERR! parent: 'through2' } npm ERR! npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request: npm ERR! c:\xampp\htdocs\liquasource\npm-debug.log /c/Program Files/nodejs/npm: line 27: 9000 Signal 112 (core dumped) "$NODE_EXE" "$NPM_CLI_JS" "$@"
```

I have tried everything I found on internet. Running it as administrator, I have also installed Python and added that to my Path variable.

I hope someone can help me with this problem..

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the problem, NodeJS comes installed with NPM, but it's a pretty old version. Just did `npm install npm -g` to resolve my problems.

**https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-node**

Answer (score 2):

npm install && npm run dev

These commands need to run on a fresh Laravel installation, otherwise you will face many errors.

As mentioned in [Laravel Documentaiton](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication)

Want to get started fast? Install the laravel/ui Composer package and run php artisan ui vue --auth in a fresh Laravel application.

Answer (score 1):

Disable AntiVirus software, if you are running any also try to run `npm cache clean`. If nothing works then alter the permissions of your node_module folder(alter the permissions of root just to check if that's the problem) and then try again. Hope this would help,,

Comment: I think it is something with the permissions.. If I try to run `npm cache clean` I get this: http://prntscr.com/9rweo2. It'd be great if you knew how to fix it..

Comment: Run command prompt as admin and try running that again, If it doesn't work try changing the permissions under the security tab of root folder. @Peurr

Comment: I did run it as administrator. What permissions do I have to change? The permissions of where Composer is installed or the permissions of my project folder?

Comment: @Peurr Try to change the permissions of your node folder and provide it with all the rights just in case.

Comment: I have found the problem, was using an old version of NPM. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a solution. Change your website folder location from Desktop or any to C:\ directly. Try again to npm install. It should work. :)